# pino-pretty does not output numbers, but only strings

Tags: pino

I have a very simple log file with as below `app.log`

```
{"level":30,"time":"2023-06-19T04:01:56.478Z","pid":2484,"hostname":"YMLTITD2227","msg":77}
{"level":30,"time":"2023-06-19T04:01:56.478Z","pid":2484,"hostname":"YMLTITD2227","msg":"42"}
```

Notice that first message is number 77, while the other is string 42. If I do `cat app.log | npx pino-pretty`, I get the below output

```
[12:01:56.478] INFO (2484):
[12:01:56.478] INFO (2484): 42
```

It does not display the numbers, but only the strings. I was hoping that pino-pretty should be able to interpret numbers as strings.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is actually a bug. I have raised this issue
https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty/issues/433